# Can entropy decrease although extremely unlikely?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

**Second Law of Thermodynamics**

From the second law of thermodynamics, the entropy of the universe must **always** increase. However, most explanations of entropy state that it is the measure of the number of possible microscopic arrangements or states of individual atoms and molecules of a system. Hence it is favourable for things to move to a state of disorder.

Consider a hot object coming into contact with a cold one. By reaching a temperature equilibrium, this it the state where entropy is maximum, and most statistically likely. However, although very unlikely, couldn't the temperature of the hot object actually increase, therefore decreasing entropy. I understand that this is almost impossible, however the probability is non zero.

So when we restate the entropy of the universe as **always** increasing, can there be situations where the entropy actually decreases although unlikely?

Something must be wrong with my intuition as stated above. What is wrong?

Comment: "So when we restate the entropy of the universe as always increasing" --no serious source should do this. To start with, it is hard to define the entropy of the universe. If you want my two cents: Read the work of Jaynes to gain a solid understanding of the second law, entropy and statistical mechanics in general. A good intro textbook, which however works with QM, is by Jochen Rau. The books by R. Balian are also very nice.

Comment: Sure entropy can fluctuate on small scales as per uncertainty principle $\Delta T \Delta S \Delta t \geq \hbar/2$.